# Get Failure reason from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Can we ***send mail only the failure reason from jenkins***, when jenkins build is getting fail. I am using Email-ext plug-in , and using that plug-in i can able send only HTML report through Jenkins .

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right plugin **Email-ext plug-in** you need to configure the global level settings for this plugin in Jenkins(setting up SMTP). Once you are done with is setup,Go to the job level settings in Jenkins and select the event as (send only on failure)

follow : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav. I am able to send mail only on build failure. But I want to send mail only the failure reason of build.

Comment: I am not getting what you want to achieve?

Comment: How I can able to send the failure cause of the build through jenkins?